# Encrypt and Decrypt iOS/Node.js Security Inquiry

Tags: ios, node.js, encryption, sha256, password-encryption

I'm currently using AES128 on both platforms and my code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27893935/2977578)

Note: I changed the code a bit to deviate from using an IV because I thought it was overkill for the purpose of my application. 

node.js:

```
    var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
    var crypto = require('crypto');
    var password = "1234567890123456";
    var salt = "gettingsaltyfoo!";
    var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(salt);
    var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, hash, { keySize: 256/32, iterations: 1000 });
    var algorithm = 'aes128';
    console.log(key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));

function encrypt(text){
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm,key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
  var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex');
  crypted += cipher.final('hex');
  return crypted;
}

function decrypt(text){
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm,key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
  var dec = decipher.update(text,'hex','utf8');
  dec += decipher.final('utf8');
  return dec;
}
```

iOS:

```
        #import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
NSString* password = @"1234567890123456";
NSString* salt = @"gettingsaltyfoo!";
-(NSString *)decrypt:(NSString*)encrypted64{

    NSMutableData* hash = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    NSMutableData* key = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA256(salt.UTF8String, (CC_LONG)strlen(salt.UTF8String), hash.mutableBytes);
    CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(kCCPBKDF2, password.UTF8String, strlen(password.UTF8String), hash.bytes, hash.length, kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA1, 1000, key.mutableBytes, key.length);
    NSLog(@"Hash : %@",[hash base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]);
    NSLog(@"Key : %@",[key base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]);


    NSData* encryptedWithout64 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:encrypted64 options:0];
    NSMutableData* decrypted = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:encryptedWithout64.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];
    size_t bytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
            kCCAlgorithmAES128,
            kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
            key.bytes,
            key.length,
            NULL,
            encryptedWithout64.bytes, encryptedWithout64.length,
            decrypted.mutableBytes, decrypted.length, &bytesDecrypted);
    NSData* outputMessage = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:decrypted.mutableBytes length:bytesDecrypted];
    NSString* outputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:outputMessage encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Decrypted : %@",outputString);


    return outputString;
}
-(NSString *)encrypt:(NSString *)toEncrypt{
    NSMutableData* hash = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    NSMutableData* key = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA256(salt.UTF8String, (CC_LONG)strlen(salt.UTF8String), hash.mutableBytes);
    CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(kCCPBKDF2, password.UTF8String, strlen(password.UTF8String), hash.bytes, hash.length, kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA1, 1000, key.mutableBytes, key.length);

    NSData* message = [toEncrypt dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableData* encrypted = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:message.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];
    size_t bytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
            kCCAlgorithmAES128,
            kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
            key.bytes,
            key.length,
            NULL,
            message.bytes, message.length,
            encrypted.mutableBytes, encrypted.length, &bytesEncrypted);
    NSString* encrypted64 = [[NSMutableData dataWithBytes:encrypted.mutableBytes length:bytesEncrypted] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSLog(@"Encrypted : %@",encrypted64);
    return encrypted64;
}
```

**MY QUESTION:** Is it okay if I hardcode the salt like this? I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt the password (the var password and NSString password will probably be hardcoded into something). I've read online that I need to keep my salt with my password in my db. If it's not okay if I hardcode my salt, how do I send it from iOS to node.js and be consistent with the salt? Should my iOS request look like this?

```
{
key:"someKeyGeneratedOnTheSpotWithRandomSalt",
password:"somePasswordGeneratedFromKey"
}
```

and in my backend check the password by pulling these fields from the database?

```
{
key:"someKeyGeneratedWhenTheUserFirstSignedUp",
password:"somePasswordGeneratedFromTheOrginalKeyWhenUserFirstSignedUp"
}
```

And then decrypt both passwords using the key and password generated from both scenarios?

OR is it okay to have a hardcoded salt, say the username, so that way the key is always the same per user?

Basically I'm confused on whether or not I have the right idea for my encryption model.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: You really shouldn't hardcode a password or encoded key in your app. This doesn't provide actual security and is only obfuscation. You can hardcode an RSA public key in the app and establish an ephemeral secret key from that with the server. Even better if you use TLS with certificate pinning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically a random salt is used and prepended to the encrypted data. It is also common to all prepend the PBKDF2 iteration count along with a version number helps for future-proofing. Finally, skipping an iv reduces the protection of the first block and you might consider an authentication hash.

This is similar to what RNCryptor does. See [RNCryptor-Spec-v3.md](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/RNCryptor-Spec-v3.md) for a detail of a encrypted message.

Notes:
I don't understand CC_SHA256 of the salt, that shouldn't be necessary.

`NSData* outputMessage = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:decrypted.mutableBytes 
length:bytesDecrypted];`
is unnecessary, just set the length of `decrypted`
`decrypted.length = bytesDecrypted;`
and use `decrypted` in place of `outputMessage`.

Comment: So i should store the key with the encrypted password in the db up a user signing up. Then whenever a user signs in, ill re encrypt it using another randomized salt, send the new key and new password and compare against the old key and old password. Is this correct? I might decide to add an iv to that later, I'm just trying to get off the ground quickly.

Comment: I haven't really examined the db part, I'll take a look. If you are going to "get off the ground quickly" make sure you add a version number to the encrypted data or you are locked in. Consider if there "really" will be an update later.

Comment: so you mean something like key = "1.0" + key;?

Comment: No, prepend to the encrypted data prior to Base64 encoding.

Comment: can you help me figure out why my iOS and Node differ in encrypted data? They both have the same key, hash, and decrypted value. but the encrypted data is different but I'm pretty sure I'm using AES 128 in both. 
IOS: vfOzya0yV9G5hLHeSh3R1g= AND                                                              NODE: 8fd7cd38dd715f9269f9eb40ecb43ab9

Comment: I've also tried decrypting the iOS in the node and it didn't work:::::
ERROR:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
CODE:
`decrypt('vfOzya0yV9G5hLHeSh3R1g==');`