# AES-256 produces different ciphertexts in iOS and Node.js with same password

Tags: javascript, objective-c, node.js, encryption, aes

So I have my iOS code:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
NSString* password = @"1234567890123456";
NSString* salt = @"gettingsaltyfoo!";
-(NSString *)decrypt:(NSString*)encrypted64{

    NSMutableData* hash = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    NSMutableData* key = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA256(salt.UTF8String, (CC_LONG)strlen(salt.UTF8String), hash.mutableBytes);
    CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(kCCPBKDF2, password.UTF8String, strlen(password.UTF8String), hash.bytes, hash.length, kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA1, 1000, key.mutableBytes, key.length);
    NSLog(@"Hash : %@",[hash base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]);
    NSLog(@"Key : %@",[key base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]);


    NSData* encryptedWithout64 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:encrypted64 options:0];
    NSMutableData* decrypted = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:encryptedWithout64.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];
    size_t bytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
            kCCAlgorithmAES128,
            kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
            key.bytes,
            key.length,
            NULL,
            encryptedWithout64.bytes, encryptedWithout64.length,
            decrypted.mutableBytes, decrypted.length, &bytesDecrypted);
    NSData* outputMessage = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:decrypted.mutableBytes length:bytesDecrypted];
    NSString* outputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:outputMessage encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Decrypted : %@",outputString);


    return outputString;
}
-(NSString *)encrypt:(NSString *)toEncrypt{
    NSMutableData* hash = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    NSMutableData* key = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA256(salt.UTF8String, (CC_LONG)strlen(salt.UTF8String), hash.mutableBytes);
    CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(kCCPBKDF2, password.UTF8String, strlen(password.UTF8String), hash.bytes, hash.length, kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA1, 1000, key.mutableBytes, key.length);

    NSData* message = [toEncrypt dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableData* encrypted = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:message.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];
    size_t bytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
            kCCAlgorithmAES128,
            kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
            key.bytes,
            key.length,
            NULL,
            message.bytes, message.length,
            encrypted.mutableBytes, encrypted.length, &bytesEncrypted);
    NSString* encrypted64 = [[NSMutableData dataWithBytes:encrypted.mutableBytes length:bytesEncrypted] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSLog(@"Encrypted : %@",encrypted64);
    return encrypted64;
}
```

and I have my node.js code:

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var crypto = require('crypto');
var password = "1234567890123456";
var salt = "gettingsaltyfoo!";
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(salt);
var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, hash, { keySize: 256/32, iterations: 1000 });

var algorithm = 'aes128';

function encrypt(text){
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm,key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
  var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex');
  crypted += cipher.final('hex');
  console.log(crypted);
  console.log(hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
  console.log(key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
  return crypted;
}

function decrypt(text){
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm,key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
  var dec = decipher.update(text,'hex','utf8');
  dec += decipher.final('utf8');
  console.log(dec);
  return dec;
}
```

**Question:** Unfortunately, though I have the same hash, key, and eventually decrypted value (meaning they can work independently), I get different encrypted values. So in one code, if I take the encrypted value and try to decrypt it in another, I get an error. When I go from iOS to node I get this error:

> ERROR:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length CODE: decrypt('vfOzya0yV9G5hLHeSh3R1g==');

Also I get these different encrypted values for the string "Hello World":

```
IOS: vfOzya0yV9G5hLHeSh3R1g==
NODE: 13b51a6785f47d8601c3a612d41b9a8b
```

How can I resolve this matter so that I can interop my iOS and Node.js, and in the future Android. I know my hashing algorithm is right for producing the SHA256 and PBDKF2 because I get the same hash and key. This means that somewhere my implementation is wrong for AES128 upon encrypting my password. Most likely my iOS code. Please let me know where my error is.

Comment: Sorry, somewhat new so I just assumed that the person that edited my question knew what he or she was doing.

Comment: You would have been better off just adding the additional information to your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33092256/451475)  asked 7 hours ago since the code is the same. And the code is just a copy of the code in this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27893935/2977578), warts and all bit the attribution has been removed.

Comment: Just for starters: `13b51a6785f47d8601c3a612d41b9a8b` is hex encoded and  `vfOzya0yV9G5hLHeSh3R1g==` is Base64 encoded which decoded to hex is: `bdf3b3c9ad3257d1b984b1de4a1dd1d6` -- still not equal. You need to perform hex dumps on each at every step to determine where the difference occurs. When you use code from another source it becomes yours and you are responsible to make it work. Tine to dive in and debug.

Comment: @zaph I should have included attribution. I overlooked this because my code is slightly different as it uses the crypto module and the CryptoJS in slightly different ways. I will make sure I do this next time regardless so thanks for pointing that out. But as for your first comment, I believe that I was warranted a new question to ask because the first question was about my security implications. This question is about a lack of interoperability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use CryptoJS, because node.js' [crypto module](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) provides everything you need for this to work. CryptoJS has a different binary representation than node.js' native Buffer, so there will be problem using both in conjunction.

Problems:

- You're using `crypto.createCipher()` which will derive the key from a password on its own in an OpenSSL compatible format. You want to use `crypto.createCipheriv()`.
- You're not passing an IV to in Objective-C which defaults to a zero filled IV. You need to do the same in node.js by initializing a zero-filled Buffer.
- You provide the key in Base64 encoded form in node.js, but you have to provide the bytes (Buffer).
- Since the key size is 256 bit you're actually using AES-256 and not AES-128. The CommonCrypto code seems to change automatically to 256 bit despite specifying 128 bit, but node.js requires you to specify 256 bit explicitly. Also, "aes128" or "aes256" will default to ECB mode in node.js, but CommonCrypto defaults to CBC mode, so you need to explicitly specify this.

Full working code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var password = "1234567890123456";
var salt = "gettingsaltyfoo!";

var sha256 = crypto.createHash("sha256");
sha256.update(salt);
var hash = sha256.digest();

var key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, hash, 1000, 32, "sha1");

var iv = new Buffer(16);
iv.fill(0);

var algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';

function encrypt(text){
  var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
  var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','base64');
  crypted += cipher.final('base64');
  return crypted;
}

function decrypt(text){
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
  var dec = decipher.update(text,'base64','utf8');
  dec += decipher.final('utf8');
  return dec;
}

console.log(encrypt("Hello World"));
```

Output:

```
vfOzya0yV9G5hLHeSh3R1g==
```

---

#### Other considerations:

- You need to generate a random IV for every encryption that you do. If you don't do this, then an attacker may see that you encrypted the same message multiple times without actually decrypting it if you use the same key every time. Since you derive a key from a password, then you can do this a bit better by generating a random salt and derive 384 bit (48 byte) from PBKDF2. Use the first 32 byte for the key and the rest for the IV.
- You need to authenticate the ciphertexts. If you don't then an attacker might mount a padding oracle attack on your system. You can easily do this by running an HMAC over the ciphertext and send the resulting tag along with it. You can then verify the tag before decryption by running the HMAC again over the received ciphertext in order to check for manipulation.
  Or you could use an authenticated mode like GCM.

Comment: Why perform a sha256 hash of the pbkdf2 salt? Note that the code is just a copy of a SO answer, not the OP's.

Comment: Thanks, I somehow don't remember that question. In any case, I forgot to remove the first sentence after solving it.

Comment: two quick questions, I'm a little new to node.js so I'm going have to look at how to use HMAC. But in the meantime if it was quick, I'd appreciate a quick code example on how to utilize it. Also I had a question about how I'd transfer iOS encrypted data to my backend. So I'm thinking in my backend, I have stored the key when the message was encrypted the first time around, and compare those two pieces with the new encrypted message and new key from my front end. Is this correct because I can't see anyway to do this without transferring my key from my front to backend.

Comment: and some help on creation of the salt/iv would be helpful as well!

Comment: @user2977578 You should have thought about the key management before beginning to program. You would need to utilize asymmetric cryptography for example with RSA, but then you could also just use TLS which has everything built in.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I am not too afraid of a weak encryption flow because my flow uses AWS Lambda, Cognito, and DynamoDB. This is for more security. I know AWS Lambda has security in mind when sending requests. What the bigger picture involves is a user sending his username and password to my AWS Lambda method which then authenticates my user using credentials provided from AWS Cognito. In this sense I probably don't need to make use of HMAC because the only way a user can make a request to AWS Lambda is if they have my Cognito credentials. Therefore I think this implementation is good enough with AWS.

Comment: Also I think I'll be storing a randomized salt per user from some id